# Webhook to discord url from firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, discord

I'm using firebase realtime database and cloud functions.  The goal is on a create event in realtime database to send a message to Discord webhook.

I'm getting a 400 status error and can't work out how to get around it.

Here is my code:

```
const WEBHOOK_URL = 'MY DISCORD WEBHOOK URL';

exports.webhook = functions.database.ref('{sessionId}').onCreate(async (snap) => {

  const sessionData = snap.val();

  const response = await request({
    uri: WEBHOOK_URL,
    method: 'POST',
    json: true,
    body: sessionData.dateCreated,
    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
  });
  if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
    throw new Error(`HTTP Error: ${response.statusCode}`);
  }
  console.log('SUCCESS! Posted', snap.ref);
```

And the error message:

```
Error ->
StatusCodeError: 400 - {"_misc":["Only dictionaries may be used in a DictType"]}
    at new StatusCodeError (/srv/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32:15)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (/srv/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:104:33)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/srv/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
    at Request.self.callback (/srv/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

Comment: `sessionData.dateCreated` is a string or an object? If a string, try `{ dateCreated: 
 sessionData.dateCreated }`

Comment: Thanks for the response @barbsan , yes that led me to the correct format.  Here is what worked in the end.  ```const response = await request({
    uri: WEBHOOK_URL,
    method: 'POST',
    json: true,
    body: {content: `A string with ${sessionData.dateCreated}` },
    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
  });```